# Focus on window of target buffer

Tags: vim-windows

Let's say I have a way of identifying (through name or number) a buffer which is already open in a window somewhere. How can I focus on the window that hosts said buffer? Can this be generalizable so that I can find this window even if it lives in another tab?

Comment: No actually I can also do it by buffer number... I have access to the whole buffer python object. I think the linked answer only adresses switching buffer by substituing the found buffer in the current window. I'm interested in jumping to *another* window where the target buffer already resides.

Comment: Ah, I see. The title contains the somewhat ambiguous "switch to it" so that's why I thought it.

Comment: Yes you're right... I changed it to make it more clear

Comment: In any case, welcome to Vi&Vim SE. :)

Comment: Thankyou that's very nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the functions `win_findbuf`, `bufnr`, and `win_gotoid` as follows:

```
let wins = win_findbuf(bufnr('name'))
call win_gotoid(wins[0])
```

This goes to the "first" buffer that contains the window, and the list will be ordered by tab and window number.  Also left as an exercise to handle the error case where *no* window contains your buffer.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thankyou.